# Using File::Path to create directory, but owner and group are not set correctly

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm trying to write a small Perl script which creates a directory structure. To create the directories, I use the standard module File::Path, as follows:

```
make_path($directory,
    {
        owner   => 'apache',
        group   => 'apache',
        mode    => 0500
    }
);
```

When executing the script, the directory is created as wanted and the umask is set as expected, but both owner and group of the file are "root". This is wrong, but where is the error? No error message is printed or given by the error-parameter.

Thanks in advance,

Jost

Comment: Also giving the numerical user and group ids does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried it and got the same outcome as you.  I looked at the documentation:

```
perldoc File::Path
```

...and no mention of 'owner' option.  However, searching the latest version (2.08, AFAICT) documentation, and it's there.  Can you check the version of the module on your system?

```
perl -MFile::Path -e 'print $File::Path::VERSION'
```

If you're not running 2.08, that might be the problem.  I'm attempting to track down the changelog for the module right now, but having difficulty...

[ Later ]

OK, so here's what you want to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use File::Path qw( make_path );

my $directory = $ARGV[0];
my $owner = 33;

make_path( $directory, { mode => 0500 } );
chown 33, 33, $directory;
```

Ultimately, the last line is the one you want to take note of.  You can't set the owner when you create it with that version of File::Path, but you can change it.  The 33 in my example is the UID of the www-data user on my system; clearly, you want to change 33 to something more sensible for your system.  Also, you will need to make sure that your script runs with privileges that are capable of doing this.  For example, if you run this as a lowly user, it won't work, but if you run it as root, the chown will work.  You might want to find some middle ground there.

Comment: Aye, that could be the answer - the version on my system is only 2.07_03. I'll try to get a newer version.

Comment: That's the same version as I have on my system, so you're not going mad.  I've updated my answer with what I believe is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: i've simply updated my File::Path version, I'm a fan of up to date systems anyway.. it did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: @Jost: Be aware that this means your script will silently fail if somebody runs it with an older version of `File::Path`.

Comment: @Keith: Ok, I'm aware of it (for now). It's ok, as the script only automates some things I had to do repeatedly on my own machine.

Comment: @Jost If the script *were* for use outside of your system, you could simply write `use File::Path 2.08;` and then instead of failing silently, it would error with "File::Path 2.08 required" on systems with an older version :)

Comment: @hobbs, it's also a good idea to add a comment explaining _why_ the script needs version 2.08, because you'll probably forget.

Comment: @hobbs: ok, that's a feature of Perl I didn't know yet. Its useful, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that this is a bug in `File::Path`; it quietly ignores keys that it doesn't recognize.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Path;

print "Using File::Path version $File::Path::VERSION with Perl $]\n";

my $tmpdir = "/tmp/file-path-test-$$";

print "Creating $tmpdir\n";
mkdir $tmpdir, 0777 or die "$tmpdir: $!\n";

my @result = File::Path::make_path
                ( "$tmpdir/new-dir",
                  { owner => 'kst',
                    mode => 0500,
                    nosuchkey => 'WTF?' } );

print "Created ( @result )\n";
```

(Note that this assumes you have an account on your system named "kst"; adjust as needed for your system.)

When I run this under `sudo` using File::Path version 2.07_03 with Perl 5.010001, the created directory is owned by `root`; when I do exactly the same thing, but using File::Path version 2.08_01 with Perl 5.014000, the directory is owned by `kst`.  In either case, there's no indication of a problem with the unrecognized keys (`owner` and `nosuchkey` for the older version, just `nosuchkey` for the newer version).

`perldoc File::Path` doesn't address this issue (unless I missed it), and I don't see any clean way for a program to determine whether the `File::Path` it's using can handle the newer options.  (You could check `$File::Path:VERSION`, but that requires knowing when a new option was implemented.)

I've just [reported this](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=70257).

Comment: You can read the [Changes](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Path/Changes) file to see that feature was added in 2.08.

Comment: Or you can call `chown` after calling `make_path` and not have to care about what version you have.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Kenny is useful only when you want to create single directory, not more nested directories - eg. `make_path ( 'foo/bar' );`
In second case only owner/group of last directory will be changed.

More correct way can be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use File::Path qw( make_path );
use File::Spec;

my $directory = $ARGV[0];
my $gid = getgrnam( "my_group" );
my $uid = getpwnam( "my_user" );

make_path( $directory, { mode => 0750 } );
my @directories = File::Spec->splitdir( $directory );
my @path;
foreach my $dir ( @directories ) {
    push( @path, $dir );
    chown $uid, $gid, File::Spec->catdir( @path );
}
```